# How can I formally verify fuzzy commitment scheme based security protocol?

Tags: protocol-design, provable-security, protocol-analysis, verifiability

I am currently working on designing a security protocol which involves usage of fuzzy commitment schemes, for. eg Reed-Solomon codes which allows us to tolerate a certain level of error.

I was wondering how one would go about formally verifying a security protocol which would use a scheme such as Reed-Solomon codes.

I searched online, and found out about tools out there such as *AVISPA*. *ProVerify* and even *Casper/FDR* which would help me test security protocols, however they do not seem to work with fuzzy commitment schemes.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but as you are looking for a formal verification, I would advise you to take a look at [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/). Even though mainly used by Academics, it provides a logical framework and an interface to write formal and interactive proofs.

Based this language there exists some libraries dedicated to cryptographic proof :

- [CertiCrypt](http://certicrypt.gforge.inria.fr/)
- [EasyCrypt](https://www.easycrypt.info/) ([tutorial](https://www.easycrypt.info/downloads/tutorial/tutorial-prg.pdf))

Example of proof :

- [Full Proof Cryptography: Verifiable Compilation of Efficient Zero-Knowledge Protocols](http://certicrypt.gforge.inria.fr/2012b.CCS.pdf)
- [Formal certification of ElGamal encryption](http://software.imdea.org/~szanella/Zanella.2008.FAST.pdf)
- [Verification of a Cryptographic Primitive: SHA-256](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/papers/verif-sha.pdf)

PHD : [Formal certification of game-based cryptographic proofs](https://pastel.archives-ouvertes.fr/pastel-00584350/document)

Other formal tools (interactive provers) can be used such as [Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/overview.html), [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), [Fstar](https://fstar-lang.org/) and [HOL](https://hol-theorem-prover.org/).
And some more readings :

- [Computer Verification in Cryptography](http://waset.org/publications/2218/computer-verification-in-cryptography)
- [Probabilistic Relational Verification for Cryptographic Implementations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nswamy/papers/probabilistic-relational-verification-for-cryptographic-implementations-final-bw.pdf)

---

**Disclaimer:** I use Coq on daily basis...

Comment: Thank you @Biv. Coq seems interesting . Let me have look into it and get back to you.